# Two urls being sent on fetch request ie. http://localhost:3000/localhost:5000/tasks/1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my app.js where the delete request is being used. I keep getting the error that i cant find the route \http://localhost:3000/localhost:5000/tasks/1 . I don't know why it is sending 2 urls. It should just be http://localhost:5000/tasks/1. I can't quite see where the mistake is. If anyone can see whats going wrong it would be appreciated.

```
import Header from './components/Header'
import Tasks from './components/Tasks'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Addtask from './components/AddTask'


function App() {

  const [showAddTask, setShowAddTask] = useState(false)

  const [tasks, setTasks ] =  useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTasks = async () => {
      const tasksFromServer = await fetchTasks()
      setTasks(tasksFromServer)
    }
    getTasks()
  }, [])

//fetch tasks
  const fetchTasks = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/tasks')
    const data = await res.json();

    console.log(data)
    return data;
  }

//Add Task
const addTask = (task) => {
  const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) +1;
  const newTask = {id, ...task}
  setTasks([...tasks, newTask]) 
};

//Delete task
const deleteTask = async (id) => {

  await fetch(`http:localhost:5000/tasks/${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
  })

  setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id))
}

//Toggle Reminder
const toggleReminder = (id) => {
  setTasks(tasks.map((task) => task.id === id ? 
  {...task, reminder : !task.reminder} : task
  ))
}

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header onAdd = {() => setShowAddTask(!showAddTask)} propShowAdd={showAddTask}/>

     {showAddTask ?  <Addtask onAdd = {addTask}/> : null}
      {tasks.length > 0 ?  
      (<Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete= {deleteTask} onToggle={toggleReminder}/> )
      :( 'No Tasks To Show' )}
    </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

Comment: You're missing `//` after the `http:` in your delete task fetch url: `http:localhost:5000/tasks/${id}`. A url that doesn't start with `//` is relative to the current page

Comment: Yep thank you. Needed another pair of eyes